# Designing an iOS View like Path

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, path, themes

What typically does Path iOS app use to make their views look so cool? Is this a specail view in iOS?

Is it a UITableView or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any special view you wanted to know about? Yes, you might wonder what's that effect  on down-left (+) button. Okay, For of the effects like *PATH APP for iPhone* you can always check [THIS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pathmenuexample) and [THIS](https://github.com/burtlo/QuadCurveMenu)

*My generalized guess would be:*

Most probably it's a `UIScrollView` (on which the main image remains on the top almost all the time) used with lots of other `UI` controls like `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, custom `UIButton` and many more of them. Important thing is they have wrote the perfect logic to set display frame for all of them. That's why It looks So organized and fluid. (Fluidity always depends on the device, of course, this app on iPhone 3GS lags, too much.)

For left and right side swipe menu, My guess would be, they are `UIView` containing `UITableView` with lots of customizations, again. Both this views are on the same `ViewController` on which Main View is there.

Comment: UICollectionView?

Comment: Possibly. Yes. I didn't know much about it at that time. :)